# What are reliable resources for weather and all other atmospheric obstructions?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, atmospheric-effects, light-pollution, weather, resource-request

Everyone knows you need clear skies to see what the stars or the Sun is doing. Weather is not too particularly hard to determine. There are many resources out there that will tell us the weather in any city. However, they very often lack other atmospheric obstructions. Naturally, light pollution is one of the biggest concerns. But another major concern is erratic atmospheric changes due to things like forest fires.

I'm looking for good resources that will tell me not only weather, but also light pollution and other obstructions such as smoke from forest fires.

(There's a solar eclipse coming up and I'm driving 500 miles to see it.)

Comment: *Weather is not too particularly hard to determine* You need to be made aware that forecasting weather accurately is exceptionally difficult, even on short time scales.  Don't underestimate this.

Comment: If you live in San Diego,  writing down "warm and sunny" is a sufficient weather forecast.  If you live in New England, don't trust any forecast more than one hour into the future.

Comment: @Stephen I mean so say there's plenty of resources.

Answer (score 2):

You might try https://clearoutside.com/forecast/50.7/-3.52  It gives weather and visibility among other things.

They have an app for iPhone and android. Advertises site was developed by astronomers.